# undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have this problem

```
undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

every answer here pointing out to the command below not being run

```
rails generate devise:install
```

However i actually complete the process of installing the devise gem also i added the omniauth-facebook gem and it works few times. but when i try to commit and load my production site it breaks and thats where the error is then i go back to my testing site it breaks too anyway heres the complete code

**gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 7.1', '>= 7.1.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.0.1'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'fog'
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'acts_as_follower', github: 'tcocca/acts_as_follower', branch: 'master'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.3'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :items do
    member do
      put "vote", to: "items#vote"
    end
  end
  resources :profiles
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  get 'pages/wish'

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root to: 'pages#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end

  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :items
    end
  end


end
```

**devise.rb:** this the only code i added to Devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FB_APP_ID"], ENV["FB_APP_SECRET"]
```

**User.rb:**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

def has_facebook_linked?
    self.provider.present? && self.uid.present?
  end

  def apply_omniauth(auth)
    update_attributes(
      provider: auth.provider,
      uid: auth.uid
    )
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
```

**OmniauthCallbacksController:**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        if current_user.present?
            current_user.apply_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
            redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: "Facebook Account Linked!"
        else
            @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
            sign_in_and_redirect @user
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This is not a well-formed question. Please see: [mcve]. What is your code? What do you *expect* to happen? Based on the above, it looks like you're just calling `User.devise` - which is not how the library works, so I don't know what you're expecting.

Comment: Edited just added more content for clarifications

Answer (score 11):

Ive got it solve on my own so what i did is adding this tag

```
extend Devise::Models
```

in my **user.rb** files

the user.rb file look like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend Devise::Models

# more code bellow....
end
```